# How do you pass Django variables that are passed to an HTML page to modal that is included in that HTML page

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I am passing a list of objects to an HTML page. On that HTML page, I can access those objects by writing something like:

```
{{ item.name }}
```

I also included a Bootstrap 4 modal on this HTML page with the following code:

```
{% include 'my_modal.html' %}
```

This modal only appears if a user clicks a button. When the user clicks that button and the modal appears, I want to be able to put {{ item.name }} in that modal, but it doesn't work. How can I use the same objects that I successfully passed to an HTML page in the modal that is included in that HTML page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pass variables into [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#include) using `with`, in the following way

```
{% include "my_modal.html" with item=item %}
```

and then `{{item.name}}` should work in `my_modal.html`